# Take max date values of range in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have this table:

```
| Name      | Date      |  
+-----------+-----------+
| Joe       | 1/18/04   |  
| Joe       | 5/08/12   |  
| Joe       | 8/01/15   |  
| Joe       | 4/03/09   |    
| Katie     | 6/7/08    |  
| Katie     | 9/16/16   |  
| Katie     | 4/29/11   |  
| Katie     | 3/30/14   |
```

I need to condense down to this:

```
| Name      | Date      |  
+-----------+-----------+
| Joe       | 8/01/15   |  
| Katie     | 9/16/16   |
```

(Only one entry per name, and the latest date for each name)

The closest I was able to get was by using `GROUP BY Name` and `MAX(Date)`, but that returned something like this:

```
| Name      | Date      |  
+-----------+-----------+
| Joe       | 9/16/16   |  
| Katie     | 9/16/16   |
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Here's my query:

```
SELECT name, MAX(date) 
FROM table1
GROUP BY Name
```

EDIT 2: Ok, I feel foolish. I my actual query was improperly joining two tables. Once I fixed that I was able to get the right data. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Show the exact query you used to get `9/16/16` for both.  Using GROUP BY and MAX should have worked.

Comment: What is datatype for date column?

Comment: The date is a datetime

Comment: The query is ok, you must have a Joe with  9/16/16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like your original query should actually work if this column is, in fact, a date as you say.  You likely DO have a row with that value in the table.  To make sure run something like this and sift through the results to see if you do in fact have a 'Joe' with '9/16/16'.

```
SELECT 
    name,
    date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date DESC) latestDate
FROM 
   table1 
ORDER BY name,latestDate
```

Then if you wanted to find the most recent this way.. rather than using a MAX().  Not that I am saying this is a better way... I'm just offering you another way of looking at this.

```
 WITH CTE_maxDates
 AS
 (
 SELECT 
    name,
    date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date DESC) latestDate
FROM 
   table1 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_maxDates
WHERE latestDate = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

What query are you using?

For this problem, this query would work assuming your date column is of data type date or string.

```
Select Name, Max(Date) from Tablename group by Name.
```

Also, check if any additional columns are causing any conflict.

Answer (score -1):

This works if your `Date` is of type `Datetime` (I tested it)

```
SELECT [Name], MAX(cast([Date] as date)) AS 'Date'
FROM "Your table name"
GROUP BY [Name]
```